# extjs4 get instance of view in controller?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am trying to get an instance of my view within the controller. How can I accomplish this. The main reason I am trying to do this is that I have a grid in my view that I want to disable until a selection from a combobox is made so I need to have access to the instance of the view.

Help?

My controller:

```
Ext.define('STK.controller.SiteSelectController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    stores: ['Inventory', 'Stacker', 'Stackers'],
    models: ['Inventory', 'Stackers'],
    views: ['scheduler.Scheduler'],

    refs: [{
        ref: 'stackerselect',
        selector: 'panel'
    }],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'viewport > panel': {
                render: this.onPanelRendered
            }
        });
    },
    /* render all default functionality */
    onPanelRendered: function () {
        var view = this.getView('Scheduler'); // this is null?
    }
});
```

My view:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '/extjs/examples/ux');
Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature',
    'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel']);

var filters = {
    ftype: 'filters',
    autoReload: false,
    encode: false,
    local: true
};

Ext.define('invtGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel',
    alias: 'widget.inventorylist',
    title: 'Inventory List',
    store: 'Inventory',
    multiSelect: true,
    padding: 20,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'invtGridDDGroup',
            dropGroup: 'stackerGridDDGroup'
        },
        listeners: {
            drop: function (node, data, dropRec, dropPosition) {
                var dropOn = dropRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + dropRec.get('ordNum') : ' on empty view';
            }
        }
    },
    features: [filters],
    stripeRows: true,
    columns: [{
        header: 'OrdNum',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'ordNum',
        flex: 1,
        filterable: true
    }, {
        header: 'Item',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'item',
        flex: 1,
        filterable: true
    }, {
        header: 'Pcs',
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'pcs',
        flex: 1,
        filterable: true
    }]
});

Ext.define('stackerGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.stackerselect',
    title: 'Stacker  Select',
    store: 'Stacker',
    padding: 20,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'stackerGridDDGroup',
            dropGroup: 'invtGridDDGroup'
        },
        listeners: {
            drop: function (node, data, dropRec, dropPosition) {
                var dropOn = dropRec ? ' ' + dropPosition + ' ' + dropRec.get('ordNum') : ' on empty view';
            }
        }

    },
    columns: [{
        header: 'OrdNum',
        dataIndex: 'ordNum',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'Item',
        dataIndex: 'item',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        header: 'Pcs',
        dataIndex: 'pcs',
        flex: 1
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            action: 'submit'
        }, {
            text: 'Reset',
            action: 'reset'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'top',
        items: [{
            id: 'combo',
            xtype: 'combobox',
            queryMode: 'local',
            fieldLabel: 'Stacker',
            displayField: 'stk',
            valueField: 'stk',
            editable: false,
            store: 'Stackers',
            region: 'center',
            type: 'absolute'
        }]
    }]
});

Ext.define('STK.view.scheduler.Scheduler', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.schedulerview',
    title: "Scheduler Panel",
    layout: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'inventorylist',
        width: 650,
        height: 600,
        columnWidth: 0.5,
        align: 'stretch'
    }, {
        xtype: 'stackerselect',
        width: 650,
        height: 600,
        columnWidth: 0.5
    }]
});
```

Comment: try this please: var view = this.getSchedulerScheduler();

Comment: No it did not do anything. Got this is firebug: TypeError:     this.getSchedulerScheduler is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var view = this.getSchedulerScheduler();

Comment: Surely I can not be the only person with this question. Someone has to know how to get the instance of the view inside the controller.

Comment: what is 'this'. Because the extjs creates automagically getters for all the view defined in the controller. Is 'this' the controller?

Comment: OK, this getter is created for it: this.getSchedulerSchedulerView(). It also adds 'View' to the end. But this returns 'constructor' in firebug, how am I supposed to access properties within the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, Extjs creates getter for your views (those listed in the controller's view array) and you get access to them:

```
var view = this.getSchedulerSchedulerView();
```

Once you have the view reference you can do this to get access to the contained grid:

```
var grid = view.down('.inventorylist');
grid.disable();
```

Comment: Yes, I see that now as found here in the documentatio at the end of "getting references":http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/mvc_pt3

Comment: Well using the code above gave me this error in firebug: TypeError: view.down is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

var grid = view.down('.inventorylist');

Comment: So you are saying all view specific functionality should remain in the view?

Comment: yes, you should keep separated wiew logic from business logic as much as possible. What if in the future you want to redesign your view? It will be easier if your view published a clear interface.
if view is a component (i´m sure it is) it has to have the down method.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. I believe you answered my questions and you have been a big help. I am just getting used to mvc approach and it has been a little challenge. I just need to keep getting my hands dirty and keep asking questions, thanks again.